# Getting Type Error with Python

Tags: python

I'm sort of new to Python and I was wondering how to fix this. I'm trying to make a currency converter for a school project for my computing class, however I'm getting an error.

Here's the code:

```
## Currency conversion calculator Mk.2 ##

# USD, JPY, EUR
GBP = ["1.66","169.14","1.21"]
# GBP, JPY, EUR
USD = ["0.60","102.20","0.73"]
# GBP, USD, EUR
JPY = ["0.0059","0.0098","0.0072"]
# GBP, USD, JPY
EUR = ["0.82","1.36","139.70"]
# Inputs and outputs
user_input = -1
output = -1

while True:
    print("")
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    print("Example: 14 GBP to USD")
    print("")
    user_input = input("How much would you like to convert? ")
    user_input = user_input.split()


    if user_input[1] == "GBP":
        if user_input[3] == "USD":
            output = user_input[3] * USD[0]
            print(output)
        elif user_input[3] == "JPY":
            print("Filler text")
        elif user_input[3] == "EUR":
            print("Filler text")

    elif user_input[1] == "USD":
        if user_input[3] == "GBP":
            print("Filler text")
        elif user_input[3] == "JPY":
            print("Filler text")
        elif user_input[3] == "EUR":
            print("Filler text")

    elif user_input[1] == "JPY":
        if user_input[3] == "GBP":
            print("Filler text")
        elif user_input[3] == "USD":
            print("Filler text")
        elif user_input[3] == "EUR":
            print("Filler text")

    elif user_input[1] == "EUR":
        if user_input[3] == "GBP":
            print("Filler text")
        elif user_input[3] == "USD":
            print("Filler text")
        elif user_input[3] == "JPY":
            print("Filler text")


    else:
        print("Please input it as something like '15 GBP to USD' remembering capitals!")
```

This is the error I got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kieran\Desktop\converter.py", line 27, in <module>
    output = user_input[3] * USD[0]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I'm on Python 3.3.3 by the way.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: Why are you using strings for numeric values? Use a float or a decimal type.

Comment: Why are you calling `split` on the input? What are you expecting users to enter?

Comment: Input "14 GBP to USD" Output "23.18"

Comment: This is crying out for a dictionary: `{'USD': {'GBP': 0.6, 'JPY': 102.2, ...}, ...}` then the maths becomes something like `output = input_num * rates[from][to]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using dictionaries instead of lists to make your life easier:

```
# USD, JPY, EUR
GBP = ["1.66","169.14","1.21"]
```

to

`currencies ={"GBP" : {"USD": 1.66, "JPY": 169.14, "EUR": 1.21}, "USD": {blah, blah}`

then to convert given the input `14 GBP to USD`:

```
(start_cur, end_cur) = user_input[1], user_input[3]   # for readabilities sake
converted = user_input[0] * currencies[start_cur][end_cur]
```

The whole program:

```
## Currency conversion calculator Mk.3 ##

currencies = {
    "GBP" : {"USD": 1.66, "JPY": 169.14, "EUR": 1.21},
    "USD" : {"GBP": 0.60, "JPY": 102.20, "EUR": 0.73},
    "JPY" : {"GBP": 0.0059, "USD": 0.0098, "EUR": 0.0072},
    "EUR" : {"GBP": 0.82, "USD": 1.36, "JPY": 139.70}
              }

while True:
    print("")
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    print("Example: 14 GBP to USD")
    print("")

    try:
        user_input = input("How much would you like to convert? ").split()
        (start_cur, end_cur) = user_input[1], user_input[3]   # for readabilities sake
        converted = float(user_input[0]) * currencies[start_cur][end_cur]  
        print(converted)

    except ValueError:
        print("Please input it as something like '15 GBP to USD' remembering capitals!")
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to overcomplicate it but I definitely will look into this

Comment: This way you don't need any if/else logic which can get messy. for instance if you have to add 5 or 6 more currency types. This will save you some headaches

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll probably be using this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
output = user_input[3] * USD[0]
```

to

```
output = float(user_input[0]) * float(USD[0])
```

**Note**

As the Error suggests, you are trying to multiply a sequence (here a string ) with a string `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`. 
Apparently, there are two issues here

1. You are indexing the wrong item. From your data, its clear, the currency value is at 0th index
2. You need to convert both the currency value  and the conversion factor to float. Alternatively, you need to re-write your conversion factor list as list of floats rather than list of strings

Comment: Comes out with another error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kieran\Desktop\converter.py", line 27, in <module>
    output = int(user_input[0]) * int(USD[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.60'

Comment: @user3143129: Please reread my answer. You caught me while I was updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are tying to multiply two strings together

`user_input[3] = "USD"`

and

`USD[0] = "0.60"`

```
output = user_input[3] * USD[0]
```

You probably meant:

```
output = float(user_input[0]) * float(USD[0])
```

btw you should probably make all these integers instead of strings

`USD = ["0.60","102.20","0.73"]` to `USD = [0.60,102.20,0.73]`

Comment: You will face errors while converting float to integer. `invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: just saw it as you were commenting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply strings in python and get an arithmetic response.  You need to convert the strings to ints.  Change the following lines:

```
USD = [0.60,102.20,0.73]
```

and

```
output = float(user_input[0]) * USD[0])
```

Comment: USD[0] is also represented as string.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to multiply a string by another string.

Try this:

```
output = float(user_input[0]) * float(USD[0])
```

user_input[3] is 'GBP' a string, I supposed you want to say 0.60